# Intercept URL before unload with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple chrome plugin that intercept the new URL before the page unload and if it contains a specific string I want to do some actions and invalidate the redirect! I have no idea how to do.. Can you help me?

Comment: I tried to use $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {...} but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`onBeforeRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) event of the `webRequest` API for Chrome extensions:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { 
        // do some actions
        // ...
        return {cancel: true}; 
    },
    // block requests matching this url
    {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Just make sure you have the right permissions in your `manifest.json` file:

> You must declare the "webRequest" permission in the [**extension manifest**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) to use the web request API, along with [**host permissions**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) for any hosts whose network requests you want to access.

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.google.com"
],
```

Comment: have I to use onBeforeRequest in the background.js?

Comment: I copied this code in my background.js with a alert to see if it works but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: If you wish to use the `webRequest` api in a blocking fashion, then you need to add the `webRequestBlocking` permission as well. Also you can use `alert` in a background page, but I prefer `console.log` myself.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a method to have the url before the request?

Comment: If you want to do something with the blocked URL you mean `details.url` contains that information inside the callback.

Comment: I need the URL before the blocked URL because I have to take the parameters of the blocked URL and append it to the old URL and then redirect to it.

Comment: I see in that case place this inside the callback function:   `chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function (tab) { /* tab.url is the current url */ })`

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript event that gets fired before the window unloads:  window.onbeforeunload

I know this works in Firefox and IE, but I've read that it doesn't always work in Chrome.

However, after a bit of digging, this seems to work in Chrome:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Your own message goes here...';
});
```

Comment: Now, the second part of the question: How to get the next URL..?

Comment: Could you return it in the return string?  Then use the return value of the beforeunload to redirect to the next URL?

Comment: No, there's no way for the *current* page to know which URL is visited after redirection. Hence my question: How would you fulfill the question's requirements using the code in your answer?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question.  I thought the original request was to block a redirect if some condition on the page was met.  IE to display a "dirty" warning if user input was not yet saved or some such...

Comment: (I am not the one who posted the question, FYI) Have another look at the question and its title.

Comment: There's no wording in the question that indicates the OP needs to know what the new URL is.  The only thing the question asks is how to intercept before the new URL is loaded and invalidate the redirect.  To me, that means it doesn't matter what the new URL is only that the page itself is being unloaded.

Comment: ["... that intercept the new URL before the page unload and **if it contains a specific string** I want to ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624363/intercept-url-before-unload-with-javascript-or-jquery) - Knowledge of the new URL is required in order to carry out the task I highlighted in the quote.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'm blind.  I kept missing "if it contains a specific string" in reference to the new URL.  You're right. Due to security considerations, is there even a way to do this?  I would think that could be a real browser security exploit.

Comment: Fortunately, that's not possible in regular web pages (client-side). However, this question is about [Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html) which have access to privileged APIs, see the link for more details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30181/discussion-between-jen-and-rob-w)

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge it is not possible.First the request will go to server.Then  server will decide  that redirect url.( i am using java)